# "The program is intended to" - is this an awkward use of the term?

Tags: meaning-in-context, legalese

From a Memorandum of Understanding template:

> The purpose of this MOU is to clearly identify the roles and responsibilities of each party as they relate to the implementation of the United States Department of Agriculture (USDA) Food Stamp Program (FSP). **The FSP is intended to** help state agencies inform low-income households about the availability, eligibility requirements, applications procedures and benefits for the program. To support this goal, Party A and Party B will conduct food stamp outreach to eligible families as described in their respective Outreach Plan.

Won't native speakers find this use of **intended to** awkward, since the **[FSP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Supplemental_Nutrition_Assistance_Program)** was intended primarily to provide indigent households with means to obtain food, not to just "inform" them?

Does this use of **intended to** create an impression of

> The sole purpose of the FSP is to help state agencies inform low-income households.

Or does it leave space for other "intentions" of the FSP's authors, such as the actual provision of help?

Comment: Perfectly idiomatic locution for this kind of document. One of its goals is...  The locution has a long history: https://books.google.com/books?id=3f9YAAAAMAAJ&printsec=frontcover&dq=%22is+intended+to%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=BxWYVJnlL4HIsQTHnoHgCQ&ved=0CC4Q6AEwAw#v=onepage&q=%22is%20intended%20to%22&f=false

Comment: It is not awkward at all. But may I ask, do you know who reads and signs this FSP MOU?

Comment: @CarSmack - There are no particular parties behind it. It's only a template. I wonder if the sentence "The moon landing program is intended to help prospective astronauts learn about the requirements for their participation in the planned missions." would be natural. That is, could we always use **is intended to** to mark some non-key goals.

Comment: Yes your moon-landing sentence is fine. A program has ultimate goals and intermediate goals. The phrase **is intended to** can refer to either. But I would not describe the goal in either statement as non-key; each is important to reaching the ultimate goal.

Comment: Thank you, @CarSmack! Very interesting. I perceived the sense of "is intended to" as equal as that of the emphatic Russian constructions "(программа) нацелена/предназначена/etc."

Comment: If you say the moon-landing program is intended to help Joe Johns get a job as a janitor in the NASA Center in Houston, then it still wouldn't be 'awkward'. It would just be wrong.

Comment: Earlier I had written two versions of an answer to your question. But both turned out rather wordy and I didn't post either one. I didn't know why you might think the phrase problematic. Then I decided to ask you the question in the comment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I agree, it's awkward.  It might not be 100% *wrong*, as we both understand what the sentence is trying to say, but it is weird nonetheless.

A better way to phrase that sentence would be

> The FSP **has provisions for** helping state agencies inform low-income households about the availability, eligibility requirements, applications procedures and benefits for the program.